# return combinations from a 3 dimensional array to 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, combinatorics

input `$chmcs` is a 3 dim. array. Expected output is a 2 dim. array of each combination of 1 dim. arrays from `$chmcs`.

Example `$chmcs`:

```
$chmcs[] = [['e1']];
$chmcs[] = [['e2'],['e3']];
$chmcs[] = [['e4','e5'],['e6'],['e7','e8']];
```

for the example `$chmcs` above, **expected, correct 2 dim. array output** must have 6 combinations:

```
[
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e4', 'e5'],
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e6'],
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e7', 'e8'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e6'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e7', 'e8']
]
```

However the function I tried below gives this incorrect output:

**my function's incorrect output:**

```
[
    ['e1', 'e2'],
    ['e1', 'e3'],
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e4', 'e5'],
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e6'],
    ['e1', 'e2', 'e7', 'e8'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e6'],
    ['e1', 'e3', 'e7', 'e8']
]
```

What is wrong with my function? May you help me for a correct function? thanks, regards.

```
$chmcs[] = [['e1']];
$chmcs[] = [['e2'],['e3']];
$chmcs[] = [['e4','e5'],['e6'],['e7','e8']];

function mcs_and(array $chmcs) : array
{
    $rootmcs = []; //output
    if (count($chmcs) < 2) {
        throw new Exception;
    }
    while ( ! empty($chmcs)) {
        $cur1 = array_shift($chmcs);
        $cur2 = array_shift($chmcs);
        foreach ($cur1 as $c1) {
            foreach ($cur2 as $c2) { 
                $rootmcs[] = array_unique(array_merge($c1, $c2));
            }
        }
        if (empty($chmcs)) {
            return $rootmcs;
        }
        array_unshift($chmcs, $rootmcs);
    }
}

print_r(mcs_and($chmcs));
```

Comment: Your expected output currently contains the exact same three elements twice. Surely, for the second half, it should say `e3` in the second position, and not `e2`?

Comment: thanks. i edited & corrected my question.

Comment: yes it does; however, my concern is to understand where my function fails, thanks.

Comment: While the question seems similar to the link in the 'Question closed', I do not think that it is the exact same problem. I would suggest to reopen the question.